# Навигация jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Добавляю на страницу плагин BookBlock. Этот плагин помогает представить любое содержимое в видео брошюры.

Проблема в том, что не работают кнопки навигации для перелистывания страниц.

Вопрос (естественно;) ): что нужно сделать, чтобы они стали работать?

Копирую код, относящийся к этому плагину.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bookblock/css/dm.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bookblock/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bookblock/css/custom.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="./bookblock/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script> 
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bookblock/css/noJS.css" /></noscript>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./bookblock/js/jquerypp.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bookblock/js/jquery.bookblock.js"></script>

//Вызываю плагин
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $( '#bb-bookblock' ).bookblock();

});
</script>

        //Управление навигацией
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

                var Page = (function() {

                    var config = {
                            $bookBlock: $( '#bb-bookblock' ),
                            $navNext    : $( '#bb-nav-next' ),
                            $navPrev    : $( '#bb-nav-prev' ),
                            $navJump    : $( '#bb-nav-jump' ),
                            bb              : $( '#bb-bookblock' ).bookblock( {
                                speed               : 800,
                                shadowSides : 0.8,
                                shadowFlip  : 0.7
                            } )
                        },
                        init = function() {

                            initEvents();

                        },
                        initEvents = function() {

                            var $slides = config.$bookBlock.children(),
                                    totalSlides = $slides.length;

                            // Добавляю события навигации
                            config.$navNext.on( 'click', function() {

                                config.bb.next();
                                return false;

                            } );

                            config.$navPrev.on( 'click', function() {

                                config.bb.prev();
                                return false;

                            } );

                            config.$navJump.on( 'click', function() {

                                config.bb.jump( totalSlides );
                                return false;

                            } );

                            // Добавляю события переворотов страниц
                            $slides.on( {

                                'swipeleft'     : function( event ) {

                                    config.bb.next();
                                    return false;

                                },
                                'swiperight'    : function( event ) {

                                    config.bb.prev();
                                    return false;

                                }

                            } );

                        };

                        return { init : init };

                })();

                Page.init();

            });
        </script>

//Вставляю в нужное мне место на странице
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 620px; min-width: 950px;">
<div id="stat"></div>
<div id="divcenter">

<div class="container">

    <header>

                <div class="support-note"><!-- lпроверка браузера с помощью modernizr -->
                    <span class="no-csstransforms">CSS трансформации не поддерживаются в вашем браузре.</span>
                    <span class="no-csstransforms3d">CSS 3D трансформации не поддерживаются в вашем браузре.<</span>
                    <span class="no-csstransitions">CSS переходы не поддерживаются в вашем браузре.<</span>
                </div>

            </header>

            <section class="main">

                <div class="bb-custom-wrapper">
                    <div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
                        <div class="bb-item">
                            <img src="./путь к файлу/1.jpg" alt="image01"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bb-item">
                            <img src="./путь к файлу/2.jpg" alt="image02"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bb-item">
                            <img src="./путь к файлу/3.jpg" alt="image03"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bb-item">
                            <img src="./путь к файлу/4.jpg" alt="image04"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bb-item">
                            <img src="./путь к файлу/5.jpg" alt="image05"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

               //Навигация
                    <nav>
                        <a id="bb-nav-prev" href="#">Дальше</a>
                        <a id="bb-nav-next" href="#">Назад</a>
                        <a id="bb-nav-jump" href="#" title="Переход к последней странице">Последняя страница</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </section>

        </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Я, конечно, уже с ума схожу. Все подряд перепробовала. Уже мозги кипят.

Что же нужно ДЕЛАТЬ?

Comment: Что в консоли? Без ошибок?

Comment: нет, ошибки ни одной нет в консоли.

Comment: Похоже у меня просто два плагина на одной странице работать не хотят. У меня еще fancybox подключен. Как можно сделать так, чтобы они не конфликтовали? $ уже заменила на jQuery. Искала дополнительные плагины, которые помогают избежать конфликта. Но нахожу только то, что решает проблему не совместимости плагинов jQurey с любыми другими плагинами, но не jQuery+jQuery.

Comment: попробуйте обернуть код инициализации каждого плагина в 

   (function ($) {
      // код
   })(jQuery)

Comment: ну а зачем вы два раза jQuery грузите то ? (даже трижды)